# Perl reference not printing the expected value

Tags: perl

This is my program but why not it is printing my array values instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my (@arr1,@arr2) = ([1,1,1,2,3,4],[5,5,5,6,9,87]);
my @arr3 = [\@arr1,\@arr2];
foreach (@arr3){
    foreach (@$_){
       print $_;
    }
}
```

Output:

`ARRAY(0x556414c6b908)ARRAY(0x556414c6b7e8)`

but why not it is printing my array values instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you weren't assigning anything to `@arr2`. You used something like the following to try to assign to `@arr2`:

```
(@arr1, @arr2) = ...;
```

However, Perl has no way to know how many scalars to assign to `@arr1` and how many to assign to `@arr2`, so it assigns them all to `@arr1`. Use two different assignments instead.

---

Secondly, `[ ]` creates an array and *returns a reference to it*, so

```
my @arr1 = [1,1,1,2,3,4];
```

assigns a single scalar (a reference) to `@arr1`. This is what you are printing. You want

```
my @arr1 = (1,1,1,2,3,4);
```

Same goes for `@arr2` and `@arr3`.

---

Therefore, your code should be

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @arr1 = (1,1,1,2,3,4);
my @arr2 = (5,5,5,6,9,87);
my @arr3 = (\@arr1,\@arr2);
for (@arr3) {
   say join ", ", @$_;
}
```

or

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @arr3 = ([1,1,1,2,3,4],[5,5,5,6,9,87]);
for (@arr3) {
   say join ", ", @$_;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the values are **array references**. To print the inner values, use dereference:

```
print @{ $array_ref };
```

For complex structures (arrays of arrays), you can use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper):

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($array_ref);
```

But it still wouldn't work. You can't assign to several arrays at once. The first array gets all the values, the remaining arrays stay empty.

Documented in [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub):

> Do not, however, be tempted to do this:
>
> ```
>     (@a, @b)   = upcase(@list1, @list2);
> ```
>
> Like the flattened incoming parameter list, the return list is also
>       flattened on return. So all you have managed to do here is stored
>       everything in @a and made @b empty.

Comment: Also, `my @arr3 = [\@arr1,\@arr2];` in this code produces an array whose first element is a reference to an array whose first element is a reference to an array whose first element is a reference to an array that might actually contain something useful.